# How much does a taxi from Warsaw center to Chopin airport cost at night?

Tags: taxis, poland, warsaw

How much does a taxi to the airport cost at night? The ride should be 25 minutes.

Comment: If it were not at night - and the weather is good, it's actually quite a nice walk.  I did it last year - took me just over 2 hours.  Of course, if you have luggage, it changes things :)

Answer (score 5):

It depends from where exactly in the centre and how much the given taxi charges per kilometre. To give you some background: all the taxis have a table with rates on their side window. Normal daytime rates vary between PLN 1.4 - 2.4 per kilometre, and there is some set multiplier for night rates (the same for all the taxis). Hotel taxis and taxis not in one of the corporations may charge even more.

My best guess is that you should expect to pay around PLN 40 - 70 for the ride.

And in Warsaw you can also use Uber if it makes it easier.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Uber's fare estimator](https://www.uber.com/fare-estimate/), the ride shouldn't cost more than 30`PLN`:

[image: uber warsaw airport]

If you haven't registered for Uber yet, you can [use a promo code](https://www.uber.com/invite/mmddi) to get a free 50`PLN` ride.